# How to preserve spatial reference using Imcrop with Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image and the spatial reference object of that image.
Now i want to crop the image by coordinates according to the spatial reference object.
The function Imcrop can only crop according the pixel coordinates. Is there a way to crop based on the world coordinates?
I tried to use Imcrop and compute for the new reference object but I get lost in the coordinate transformation.

An example of the reference object after warping an Image.

```
imref2d with properties:

       XWorldLimits: [-775.4357 555.5643]
       YWorldLimits: [-488.3694 523.6306]
          ImageSize: [1012 1331]
PixelExtentInWorldX: 1
PixelExtentInWorldY: 1
ImageExtentInWorldX: 1331
ImageExtentInWorldY: 1012
XIntrinsicLimits: [0.5000 1.3315e+03]
YIntrinsicLimits: [0.5000 1.0125e+03]
```

What I actually want to do is to crop the image such that the point (0,0) is the center of the cropped image.

Comment: When you say "spatial reference" you mean that you have a transformation between world coordinate and pixel coordinate?

Comment: I think that i have that. I added some info to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to you spatial reference each pixel has a dimensions of `1 x 1` in world coordinates. Therefore if you want to convert between world coordinate `(Xw,Yw)` and image coordinate `(Xi,Yi)` do the following:

```
Xi = round(abs(-775.4357 - Xw))

Yi = round(abs(-488.3694 - Yw))
```

So if you want to crop the image such that the real world coordinate `(0,0)` will be the center of the new cropped image and the size of the new image will be width on height than the rectangle for `imcrop` will be

```
[(755 - width) (488 - height) width height]
```